How to avoid error ('cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values', 'Conversion failed for column position with type object') in Airflow?
I got this task in my dag:
@task
def get_result_from_records_api(api, tries: int, result_from_salons_api: list):
    salon_ids_list = result_from_salons_api[1]
    # result is 4 pd.DataFrames
    result_from_records_api = get_data_or_raise_error_with_retry(api.get_records_staff_sales_of_services_goods, tries, salon_ids_list=salon_ids_list)
    # make lists for dfs
    records_lst = []
    staff_from_records_lst = []
    services_sales_lst = []
    good_sales_lst = []
    # put dfs in lists
    records_lst.append(result_from_records_api[0])
    staff_from_records_lst.append(result_from_records_api[1])
    services_sales_lst.append(result_from_records_api[2])
    good_sales_lst.append(result_from_records_api[3])
    # make dict with lists
    result_dict = {
        'records': records_lst
        , 'staff_from_records': staff_from_records_lst
        , 'services_sales': services_sales_lst
        , 'good_sales': good_sales_lst
    }
    return result_dict

This task returns 4 pandas.DataFrames without error (returned values is correct).
I've tryed put result in list, tuple, dictionary, but every time I get error:
{xcom.py:664} ERROR - ('cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values', 'Conversion failed for column position with type object'). If you are using pickle instead of JSON for XCom, then you need to enable pickle support for XCom in your airflow config or make sure to decorate your object with attr.

How to avoid this error?
P. S. I already enable_xcom_picking in docker-compose.yml:
AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING=true

Airflow 2.8.2
Python 3.11

I solved problem by converting pd.DataFrames to dict:
@task
def get_result_from_records_api(api, tries: int, result_from_salons_api: list):
    salon_ids_list = result_from_salons_api[1]
    result_from_records_api = get_data_or_raise_error_with_retry(api.get_records_staff_sales_of_services_goods, tries, salon_ids_list=salon_ids_list)
    records = result_from_records_api[0].to_dict()
    staff_from_records = result_from_records_api[1].to_dict()
    services_sales = result_from_records_api[2].to_dict()
    good_sales = result_from_records_api[3].to_dict()
    result = [records, staff_from_records, services_sales, good_sales]
    return result

